# display certain element inside a display:none block

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code:

```css
p{
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 }
 
p i{
   width:25px;
   height:25px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   left: 0;
   background: pink;
   display:inline-block!important;
  }
```

```html
<p> <i></i> I must be disappeared </p>
```

Is it possible to display an item inside a `display:none` block

Is there any other way can I show the **`<i>`** only visible but not the non-tagged text 'I must be disappeared' ?

PS: I don't want to add any other tag for the text 'I must be disappeared'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not forget the `visibility` property

Instead of using `display:none;` use `visibility:hidden;`

Try this

```css
p{
 visibility: hidden;
 position:relative;
 }
 
p i{
   background: pink;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;  
   position: absolute;
   border-radius:50%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   visibility: visible !important;
  }
```

```html
<p> <i></i> I must be disappeared </p>
```

Another approach

Hide the text using `text-indent` property

It won't produce any scrollbars unless it is in positive numbers.

```css
 p{
     text-indent: -9999px;
     position:relative;
     }
     
    p i{
       background: pink;
       display: inline-block;
       cursor: pointer;
       height: 20px;
       width: 20px;  
       position: absolute;
       border-radius:50%;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
      }
```

```html
<p> <i></i> I must be disappeared </p>
```

Comment: This is it, thanks text-indent helped me